# FlexSlider page offset (like Facebook)

Tags: flexslider

I'm using FlexSlider 2 and I'm trying to apply an horizontal page offset (left and right) to my slider, something like the mobile Facebook app which as you are browsing the images, you can see a small part of the previous and next image

Sample image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QMK9.jpg

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I know this was asked three years ago but it seems like there are quite a few versions of this same question on google so I figured I'd answer it now so other people don't have to fight with this.

The trick is to add some padding to your `.flex-viewport` element. Has to be padding and it can't be any higher or lower on the food chain. If its on the list it will add padding to the left but never show the padding on the right; if its on your wrapper the list won't properly overflow and you won't get to see the *preview* of the next items.

```
.flex-viewport {
   padding: 0 75px;
}
```